# "AttributeError" in Selenium Web Driver using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, attributes

I'm writing simple test for calculator on Python. I'm getting this error `AttributeError: 'CalculatorTesting' object has no attribute 'driver'`. I'm a newbie in python so please show me my mistake. Here is my code:

```
def SetUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:\chromedriver.exe')
    self.driver.get('http://qa-test.klika-tech.com/');

def test_01(self):
    driver = self.driver
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/ul[1]/li[5]').click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/ul[2]/li[5]').click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/ul[1]/li[5]').click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/ul[2]/li[7]').click()
    self.result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="display"]').text

    assert self.result is "10"

def ShutDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

all xpaths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found a mistake. There was big 'S' in 'setUp' class.